Is the fact that I have a ton of disc things in System Monitor > File Systems that all have either 90% or 100% bad?
many disc icons of varying filenames all with either 90% or 100% s
I tried opening Steam recently, but it said that I don't have 250MB to install an update. For some reason, I didn't believe it, but this may prove it to be right. Help.
Edit: It may be good to say: I am a complete newbie when it comes to the technical side of Ubuntu or really anything. I have no idea how to use the Terminal. I tried running df a few times but I can't decode what that all says, at least not on my own.

if you search man you will always get a page which describes the Linix coomand and the options to use. In the case of df it produces this page

Please look at the info on this site and then use edit to add some info to your question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
